# Boost module and Access log how to get statistic

Tags: nodes, caching

I have [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module installed and enabled ajax statistics option in statistics module.
So I have page views statistics for boost cached pages.

But I want use [Browsing History Recommender](https://www.drupal.org/project/history_rec) module which need access log data from statistics module, and this data not available for boost cached pages.

How to write access logs for boost cached pages?